# How to convert text pdf to image pdf using ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I need to convert text in pdf file to images, so users cannot copy it from the pdf etc.

This should be equivalent to converting the entire pdf to a set of images and then merging them to one single document. I did so, but it seems slow, is there any way to do it with ghostscipt options?

Answer (score 1):

Welp, looks like I only need to specify option `-dNoOutputFonts`.